# Exit Chat Window When Finished In Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm trying to build an interface so I can load a chat window with
messages I can read in the window. The user presses enter and the message index is incremented
so the next message is displayed. After the last message is displayed for
e.g. lvl 7, event 1 I would like the window to close.

The 3 parameters are the level, event, messageindex.

What happens is I don't see the chat window and no messages are
displayed in the window. How can i modify the algorithm so
that I read all the messages for the level and event and then
the window closes properly?

```
...
Debug.Log("File size is" + sizeoffile);
for (int i = 0; i < sizeoffile; i++)
{
    if ((storyitemData["storyline"][i]["event"].ToString() == eventno.ToString()) & (storyitemData["storyline"][i]["level"].ToString() == levelno.ToString()) & (storyitemData["storyline"][i]["index"].ToString() == msgindex.ToString()))
    {
        Debug.Log("read message was called with message index " + msgindex + " and the content is " + storyitemData["storyline"][i]["content"].ToString());

        //check that this is right
        txtlbl.GetComponent<Text>().text = storyitemData["storyline"][i]["content"].ToString();
    } 
    else if ((storyitemData["storyline"][i]["event"].ToString() == eventno.ToString()) & (storyitemData["storyline"][i]["level"].ToString() == levelno.ToString()) & (storyitemData["storyline"][i]["index"].ToString() != msgindex.ToString()))
    {
        msgindex = 1;
        chatwindow.active = false;
    }
}
```

**Example JSON**

```
{
   "storyline":[
      {
         "level":1,
         "event":1,
         "index":1,
         "content":"hello"
      },
      {
         "level":1,
         "event":1,
         "index":2,
         "content":"yes I saw that"
      },
      {
         "level":7,
         "event":1,
         "index":1,
         "content":"can I buy a sandwhich?"
      },
      {
         "level":7,
         "event":1,
         "index":2,
         "content":"thank you"
      },
      {
         "level":7,
         "event":1,
         "index":3,
         "content":"Salt please"
      },
      {
         "level":7,
         "event":2,
         "index":1,
         "content":"Java was"
      },
      {
         "level":7,
         "event":2,
         "index":2,
         "content":"my first language"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways you can handle this and without more code is hard to determine exactly what your setup is. All you have really shown us is that you are passing in a specific index to the list but for some reason still iterating over a list with a size of `sizeoffile` which is not mentioned at all.

I am also not sure if you intended this, but in your if conditionals, you are not using a  `&&` AND operator, but a [`bit-wise`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) `&` AND operator, which is different.

You can simply add another conditional check first to see if the current index you are reading is about to exceed the container type you are using.

```
if((storyitemData["storyline"].Count) <= msgindex)
{
    // we reached the end of the container, so disable our chat window
}
else if((storyitemData["storyline"][i]["event"].ToString() == eventno.ToString()) & (storyitemData["storyline"][i]["level"].ToString() == levelno.ToString()) & (storyitemData["storyline"][i]["index"].ToString() == msgindex.ToString())))
{
...
}
```

If what I have mentioned does not work, please add more detail to your question, and a bit more code would not hurt either. Adding the original container of the structure you are serializing to JSON would help. Is there a reason you are serializing an entire chat log to JSON to pass around your game?